# Multple urls for a product with multiply categories

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, seo

I have a cctv camera shop and
I'm using the last version of joomla and virtuemart.

I have a "bullet hd camera" the categories are:

> camera --> hd-camera --> bullet-hd-camera

bullet-hd-camera is a subcategory for hd-camera and hd-camera is a sub-category for camera

I assigned the product to all the 3 categories so when a user clicks on hd-camera in the menu, the user could see all the cameras in hd-camera's subcategories including bullet cameras.

The problem is the product has 3 different urls.

1. sitename.com/camera/the-pruduct-detail
2. sitename.com/camera/hd-camera/the-pruduct-detail
3. sitename.com/camera/hd-camera/bullet-hd-camera/the-pruduct-detail

and thats totally bad seo-wise

How can I have only the third url for the product?
How can I solve this?

Another problem is recently only the third product page displays correctly.

ERRORS IN CONSOLE:

1.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:10
دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:14

2.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:14
دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:22

4.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:22
cloud-zoom.1.0.3.js:418

5.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at cloud-zoom.1.0.3.js:418
jquery.flexslider-min.js:5

6.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.flexslider-min.js:5
دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:50

7.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at دوربين-مداربسته-هايک-ويژن-مدل-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail:50
%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B3%D…A%DA%A9-%D9%88%D9%8A%DA%98%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-ds-2ce16d0t-it1-detail

8.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd party component such as ReDJ to manually create redirects from the first 2 URL's to the 3rd URL?

[ReDJ Component](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/redj/)

Edit: [Here](https://www.selfget.com/documentation/redj-joomla25/create-a-redirection-rule.html) is a bit more info about using regular expressions with ReDJ, additionally the component follows Henry Spencers implementation of these redirect rules, which can be found [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Regards
D

Comment: it's hard to do this manually for a large number of products

Comment: @kiasati Not necessarily - ReDJ supports regular expressions - I've updated my answer with some more info :)

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart has a setting named "**Force canonical category**" within the product form. You are advised to use that setting, when a product belongs in more than 1 category.
This will actually add a [canonical tag](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls) to your product pages, indicating the search engines which page to index.

As for your js errors, please go to the Virtuemart Configuration > Templates and enable the setting:  *Use Joomla jQuery framework in FE* . If this does not help, please address to your template developer.